# How do I use a for loop for iterating the 3rd number in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

If I have a list such as:

```
set = [[1, 3, **4**, 10], [2, 4, **7**, 1], [1, 4, **4**, 8]]
```

and I want to make a loop where it will repeat the process X times for each sub-list, where X is the 3rd number of each list.

For example, draw a square **4** times, then make a draw **7** times, then draw it **4** times.

I am not necesserily looking for the code of how to produce the example, but just an explanation of *how* to tell my loop to do something **x** times based on a number in a position in a list.

Comment: `for sublist in set: print(sublist[2])`?

Comment: or perhaps `for sublist in set: for _ in range(sublist[2]): `

Comment: Since you said you're new to Python, know that using `set` as a variable name could cause issues in some scripts, since you can make an actual [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) with the `set()` function.

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? If so, please consider accepting (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 equivalent ways to structure your logic. Which you choose depends on context and the nature of your function.

```
lst = [[1, 3, 4, 10], [2, 4, 7, 1], [1, 4, 4, 8]]
```

**Option 1**

As suggested in comments, use a nested `for` loop.

```
def f(x):
    print(x)

for sublst in lst:
    for _ in range(sublst[2]):
        f(sublst)
```

**Option 2**

Add a parameter `n` to your function and move the `for` loop to the function that's doing.

```
def f(x, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(x)

for sublst in lst:
    f(sublst, sublst[2])
```

While ordinarily the advice is, "Each function should do one thing," if the very nature of the function is to run a certain number of times, then the second option may be viable.

In addition, do not name variables after classes, e.g. `set` is not a good choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a list of lists, right?

```
your_set = [[1, 3, 4, 10], [2, 4, 7, 1], [1, 4, 4, 8]] # naming a variable with a keyword argument is not a smart move btw

for iter_list in your_set:
    for _ in range(iter_list[POSITION_OF_THE_NUM_YOU_WANT]):
        DO_SOMETHING()
```

Comment: ive been trying this but i get an error saying iter_list[position]  cant be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map functionality in python:

```
set = #your list

def func(ll):
    return ll[2]

map(func, set)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that I understand your question, but I if I do then something like the following should work:

```
# Create your input set.
my_set = [[1, 3, 4, 10], [2, 4, 7, 1], [1, 4, 4, 8]]

# Define a generic function. It sounds like you might use draw_square here.
def do_something():
    print("Doing something!")

# Loop through each list in your input.
for input_list in my_set:
    # Use the third element of the list to determine how many times
    # to do something (draw squares in your case).
    num_actions = input_list[2]
    for _ in range(num_actions):
        # This could be a function or any other logic you want.
        do_something()
```

This code will loop through each list in my_set and for each list will call the function do_something x times, where x is the third element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just collect the 3rd element and then use it as range int :

```
set_1 = [[1, 3, 4, 10], [2, 4, 7, 1], [1, 4, 4, 8]]

#fake data

def print_hello(x):
   return x[::-1]


#collecting the 3rd element
data=map(lambda x:x[2],set_1)


#3rd element times
for i in data:
   for k in range(i):
      print(print_hello('hello_world'))
```

output:

```
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
dlrow_olleh
```